# Cannot connect to Xfce with remote desktop

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xrdp

I installed xrdp and xfce on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install xfce4 xrdp -y

sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
sudo systemctl restart xrdp

sudo ufw allow 3389

reboot
```

Now when using "Microsoft Remote Desktop" app, it opens for like 0.5 second (black) then quickly closes without any errors/etc.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, the solution is:

1. Edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

`sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`

2. Delete these lines

> test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
>
> exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession

3. Instead type the following at same place:

> startxfce4

4. Restart xrdp

`sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart`

Answer (score 3):

If you have not logged out locally from the machine. That could be the problem. Trying to connect via XRDP while logged on locally will not work. Coincidentally I just configured XRDP on one of my machines this morning.

[This guide might help.](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16637)