# Cannot remote login when removing xfce

Tags: 20.04, gnome, remote

I have Windows 10 machine that I want to use to remote login to my Ubuntu laptop. I installed xrdp on the laptop and when I try to connect to it through Remote Desktop Connection on Windows I get a black screen for about a second and then the a Remote Desktop Connection shuts down and I'm back on my Windows desktop, not on the Ubuntu.

If I install xfce on the laptop I can use the Remote Desktop Connection tool to connect but then I get the xfce skin/theme, and I would like to use the default Gnome skin/theme I also use when I work on the laptop.

So I think I don't have a client to use when I use the Remote Desktop Connection tool. Is there a way to just use the default Gnome skin/theme?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question. The problem is that Remote Desktop Connection crashes back to the windows desktop. So I can't connect to Ubuntu. How can I make xrdp work connect to GNOME?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it back up and running by using:

```
echo "gnome-session" > ~/.xsession
chmod +x ~/.xsession
sudo systemctl restart xrdp.service
```

Answer (score 0):

This link solved my problem:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1388619/1692873

In case anyone else runs into this problem, the solution is:

Edit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

Delete these lines
test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession

exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession

Instead type the following at same place:
startxfce4

Restart xrdp
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart